# What is the correct way to pronounce iodine?

Tags: nomenclature

I have always said it like 'io-deen' because whenever 'ine' is used (eg. amine, or fluorine) it is said that way. Sometimes I'm corrected by people who think it should be pronounced 'io-dyne', which is correct?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_UB6khjYDA

Comment: Thanks @manshu but I can't use u tube with my device.

Comment: it is both of them...may be bcz of the difference in the pronunciation in Britain and USA

Comment: You might find better answers on [english.se].

Comment: Thanks @Loong but I don't want to start another site the answers here were fine.

Comment: There may not be any such thing as "correct". Customary is the best you will get and that varies from place to place. Hell, we can't get international agreement on how to pronounce or spell aluminium/aluminum even though the american preference is obviously wrong. ;-)

Comment: I feel like both pronunciations are correct.

Answer (score 6):

Manshu is correct,in British English we pronounce iod**ine** as in s**een** while in North American English we pronounce it as in m**ine**.

Comment: Some countries use British English as their official language,so depends on which country you live .

Comment: I live in Australia.

Comment: So in British English do they pronounce amine and flourine differently also?

Comment: No, ine in both words are pronounced as in s**een** in British English.

Comment: I think it is fine for you to use British English.

Answer (score 1):

Or we could just use German.  In German they do not use the suffix for halogens at all so that "iodine" is just "Jod".  Now all we have to remember is that you don't pronounce the long "i", instead using the usual "j"/"y" consonant sound.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other halogens, iodine is pronounced eye - o - deen  (especially by chemists) .

Comment: Not in the USA. I’m a lifelong chemist and it is as in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you talking to? To non-chemists (in the US), just say i-oh-dyne.

But if you are talking with chemists, say i-oh-deen.

If you are talking to a mix of chemists and non-chemists, decide which you would like to be classified as.

Or, you could say "element 53".

Answer (score -3):

Think about how other halogens are pronounced: fluor-een, chlor-een, brom-een, astat-een, and newly named tenness-een. Why would it be io-dyne and not iod-een?